# Convert TeX to a plain string for use on http://api.mathjs.org/v4

Tags: javascript, api, math, tex, converters

I'm very very new to TeX, in fact I discovered it within the past hour. I was wondering if I could convert something like this:

```
$$ (3\times10^{-9})\times(7\times10^{3})  $$
```

Into something like this:

```
(8*10^−9)*(7*10^3)
```

I've been looking at some things about MathJax, but I'm not sure it's right for me. I plan to use the math.js REST API to give me an answer to the TeX, however I'm not sure how I can convert the TeX into a plain string anyway. Hopefully this makes sense.

It needs to be in Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use a JavaScript library.  MathJax is one among many.  Google is your friend here.

Comment: @duffymo I'm not sure how I would use MathJax though. That's my only concern.

Comment: It's a javascript library.  Include it in your page and let it render the equation.

Comment: Think about katex: https://katex.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly but it accomplishes what you need for simple expressions:

```js
var myString = '$$ (3\times10^{4})\times(7\times10^{2})  $$';
var myRegexp = /\^{([^}]*)}/g;

var myOutput = myString.replace(/\times/g, 'x');
myOutput = myOutput.replace(/\$\$/g, '');

myOutput = myOutput.replace(myRegexp, "^$1");

console.log(myOutput);
```

If your Tex expressions will be more complex, you could give it a try to [math-expressions](https://github.com/kisonecat/math-expressions). It has a `fromLatex` functionality, although I have yet to test it.